# Can't parse widget radio button

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I'm creating wordpress theme with custom widgets, so i want to make a sample widget with 3 radio buttons, so far so good, but the update() function, doesn't work well here is my code :

```
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

$instance = $old_instance;

$instance['default-image'] = strip_tags($new_instance['default-image']);
$instance['post-image'] =  strip_tags($new_instance['post-image']);
$instance['link-image'] =  strip_tags($new_instance['link-image']);

return $instance;
```

}

```
function form( $instance ) {

$defaults = array('default-image' => true, 'post-image' => false, 'link-image' => false );
$instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); 

?>

<p>
    <input name="option" type="radio" <?php checked($instance['default-image']); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('default-image'); ?>"/> 
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'default-image' ); ?>"><?php _e('Default image'); ?></label>
</p>
<p>
    <input name="option" type="radio" <?php checked( $instance['post-image']); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post-image'); ?>" /> 
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post-image' ); ?>"><?php _e('First post image'); ?></label>
</p>
<p>
    <input name="option" type="radio" <?php checked( $instance['link-image']); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link-image') ?>" /> 
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link-image' ); ?>"><?php _e('Image from link'); ?></label>
</p>
```

i will provide them in widget() with $instance['default-image'], $instance['post-image'], $instance['link-image'], but for now on "Save" button or (refresh on admin page) selected option disappears . If anyone can tell me where i'm wrong, i will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer on this questiton, that i found after several hours of investingating is that there isn't clear way to do it. Name attribute on "radio" buttons, should be same foreach button, but to work normally (to save and get saved values), name should be given by wordpress via echo ($this->get_field_name('default/post/link-image'); i found another solution using numeric values : 
update function ():

```
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

    $instance = $old_instance;

    $instance['rating'] = ( isset( $new_instance['rating'] ) && $new_instance['rating'] > 0 && $new_instance['rating'] < 4 ) ? (int) $new_instance['rating'] : 0;

    return $instance;
}
```

and :

```
function form( $instance ) {

        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array)$instance, $defaults ); 
        //default value
        $rating = ( isset( $instance['rating'] ) && is_numeric( $instance['rating'] ) ) ? (int) $instance['rating'] : 1;
        ?>
            <p>
            <legend>Use image for:</legend>
                <input type="radio" id="<?php echo ($this->get_field_id( 'rating' ) . '-1') ?>" name="<?php echo ($this->get_field_name( 'rating' )) ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $rating == 1, true) ?>>
                <label for="<?php echo ($this->get_field_id( 'rating' ) . '-1' ) ?>"><?php _e('Default image') ?></label> <br />

                <input type="radio" id="<?php echo ($this->get_field_id( 'rating' ) . '-2') ?>" name="<?php echo ($this->get_field_name( 'rating' )) ?>" value="2" <?php checked( $rating == 2, true) ?>>
                <label for="<?php echo ($this->get_field_id( 'rating' ) . '-2' ) ?>"><?php _e('First image post') ?></label> <br />

                <input type="radio" id="<?php echo ($this->get_field_id( 'rating' ) . '-3') ?>" name="<?php echo ($this->get_field_name( 'rating' )) ?>" value="3" <?php checked( $rating == 3, true) ?>>
                <label for="<?php echo ($this->get_field_id( 'rating' ) . '-3' ) ?>"><?php _e('Image from internet. Note please save first') ?></label> <br />  
            </p>
    <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `strip_tags` function really needed ?

```
function update($new, $old) {
    return $new;
}
```

I'm using this with my widgets ^^

Comment: this doesn't make any difference and if it was <input type="text" /> it would be huge mistake (i think so) if you don't put strip_tags();

Comment: since it's an input text only accessible in the admin panel, it'll be used by someone who can access pretty much anything on your website, so trying to hack it would be useless ^^